# mysql connecting to remote host fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

In my script on de webserver I'm trying connect to mysql through the (good old) mysql_connect() to an ip (db server) in the same network.

MySQL keeps throwing me the error:
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'dbname'

This seems like the db is being searched on the localhost (webserver) instead the IP I've entered (db server).

I've checked the my.cnf and can't find a bind-address or whatever.

When I connect through mysqli_connect(), the connection can be made, so there shouldn't be a firewall issue I guess.

Reason I'm still using mysql_connect is because i'm transferring a big website to a new server, and there is no time to change the function through all the script.

Anybody familiar with this problem and got any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

**Update: piece of code**

```
$link = mysql_connect("12.34.56.78", "username", "password");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use dbname : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: We need to see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have "SQL safe mode" disabled in your php.ini file.

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect) of mysql_connect on the `server` parameter:

> **server**
> The MySQL server. It can also include a port number. e.g. "hostname:port" or a path to a local socket e.g. ":/path/to/socket" for the localhost.
> If the PHP directive mysql.default_host is undefined (default), then the default value is 'localhost:3306'. **In [SQL safe mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode), this parameter is ignored** and value 'localhost:3306' is always used.

Similar filtering applies to the `username` and `password` parameters:
The `username` paramter defaults to the name of the user that owns the server process and `password` defaults to an empty string.

You can read more on SQL safe mode from here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the php is searching on the localhost but is using the username "". I think you have a problem with your user/pass combination and are also putting the ip address in the wrong place. Could you paste your code?